# Consuming Azure Queue message in Java using BrokeredMessage message . getBody() retruns some header information, How to get rid of it?

Tags: java, azure, queue, brokeredmessage

I am trying to receive Azure Queue Message from Java. I am able to receive message using BrokeredMessage  in java. (I am novice to java).

My problem is message.getBody() is returning some header information as well (Not just the message as I need).

```
I get     string3http://schemas.mi@string3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/?? message appended with my body in front of it. How can I get rid of this header information.
```

And I also I noticed i get message in two batches. (Not the whole lot at once)

```
My first batch of message.getBody()returns below message
'@string3http://schemas.mi'
My Second batch of message.getBody()returns below message
@crosoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/?? + My actual message.
```

MY total message size is less than 500B, But I have set byte size to 4096. So is is not splinting because of size issue.

This is my receiver code I use.

```
ReceiveMessageOptions opts = ReceiveMessageOptions.DEFAULT;
opts.setReceiveMode(ReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK);

while (true)
{
ReceiveQueueMessageResult resultQM =
service.receiveQueueMessage("MyqueueName", opts);
BrokeredMessage message = resultQM.getValue();
if (message != null && message.getMessageId() != null)
{

byte[] b = new byte[4096];
String s = null;
int numRead = message.getBody().read(b);
while (-1 != numRead)
{
s = new String(b);
s = s.trim();
System.out.print(s);
numRead = message.getBody().read(b);
}
}

}
```

This is the total output of System.out.print(s);. (But in two batches as I mentioned before)

```
total output
string3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/??+ My actual message.
```

Any Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting the above sample from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues#receive-messages-from-a-queue). Before proceeding with the Code, we need to understand about Receive Mode Lock types which are `PeekLock` and `ReceiveAndDelete`

**ReceiveAndDelete:**

> When using the ReceiveAndDelete mode, receive is a `single-shot operation` - that is, when Service Bus receives a read request for a
>   message in a queue, it marks the message as being **`consumed and returns it to the application`**. ReceiveAndDelete mode (which is the default
>   mode) is the simplest model and works best for scenarios in which an
>   application can tolerate not processing a message in the event of a
>   failure. To understand this, consider a scenario in which the consumer
>   issues the receive request and then crashes before processing it.
>   Because Service Bus will have marked the message as being consumed,
>   then when the application restarts and begins consuming messages
>   again, it will have missed the message that was consumed prior to the
>   crash.

**PeekLook**:

> In PeekLock mode, receive becomes a `two-stage operation`, which makes
>   it possible to support applications that cannot tolerate missing
>   messages. When Service Bus receives a request, it finds the next
>   message to be consumed, **`locks it to prevent other consumers receiving it`**, and then returns it to the application. After the application
>   finishes processing the message (or stores it reliably for future
>   processing), it completes the second stage of the receive process by
>   calling Delete on the received message. **When Service Bus sees the
>   Delete call, it will mark the message as being consumed and remove it
>   from the queue.**

You are trying with the PeekLock Mode, in which you need to explicitly call the `deleteMessage(message)` in order to mark the message as being consumed unless you didn't call this method, even though it looks like consumed, but it not actually consumed. It still in the Queue.

I think the *header* which you are mentioning is not the actual header, **it was the initial message in the queue, which is actually not consumed at all**

You can check this like change your code like the below and try

```
if (message != null && message.getMessageId() != null)
{

byte[] b = new byte[4096];
String s = null;
int numRead = message.getBody().read(b);
while (-1 != numRead)
{
s = new String(b);
s = s.trim();
System.out.print(s);
numRead = message.getBody().read(b);
}
//Add the below to ack that you are consumed the message
service.deleteMessage(message);
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Jayendaran for your response. Chaing the mode type from PeekLock to ReceiveAndDelete did not solve the issue.

However, I found the solution 
Steaming the message before sending solves the problem.

Instead of this

```
BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(encryptData);
message.ContentType = "application/json";
testQueueSender.Send(message);
```

Do this to sovle the problem

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptData);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes, writable: false);
BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(stream);
message.ContentType = "application/json";
testQueueSender.Send(message);
```

But I still receive the message in two parts for some reason. the first part is 27 bytes fixed all the time. But I don't have this problem in.NET.

Regards